# Please help me identify my bonsai tree?

Tags: identification, plant-health, bonsai

I've looked online to try to identify the type of tree that it is so I can take better care of it in regards to watering, fertilizing, & the environment. So far I've come up with nothing & it's starting to wilt, any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to water it every day or every other day by immersing the entire pot in a bucket of water until the soil stops bubbling.  Do it now. (wonderful skillets)!!

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely <strike>a ficus</strike> an olive.

You've got to treat it like a bonsai <strike>ficus</strike> olive and not a regular <strike>ficus</strike> olive.

here is a link with a care guide: https://www.bonsaiempire.com/tree-species/olive

Comment: To me it seems more a bad olive tree, but I'm not a bonsai expert.

Comment: I think you might be correct. The trunk looks closer to an olive.